# Addition overloading in Python behaviour x+y vs y+x

Tags: python, oop, operator-overloading

In Python if I have

```
class Foo:
  def __add__(self, other):
    return 123
```

then I can do `Foo()+1` and get 123.

But if I do `1+Foo()` I get an exception because int doesn't know how to add Foos.

Is there a workaround so that 1+Foo() works too?

Answer (score 3):

Implement the [`__radd__()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) as well.